# Theoretically how does column store fetch more than one column

Tags: database, database-design

Given the following table

```
name:  my_name: 01, your_name: 02
id: my_id: 01: your_id: 02


# Here is an equivalent row store sql query
SELECT p.id FROM personal_info as p WHERE p.name = my_name
```

What does the lookup look like? Does it do a O(1) check on name, and then scan the entire column in id? If so is this scan a O(n) scan or O(logn) scan? How is the performance different than row store scan?

Answer (score 1):

The complexity of scan depends on which kind of your database index is.

If the index is hash-type, the scan is O(1);
If the index is B-tree(or B+, B-epsilon), scan complexity is O(log N).

If there is no index on this column, the scan will have to perform one row by another, the complexity is O(N).

Consider the slow of random disk visitation, hash index is the best choice.